# SSRS Drop Down List Values

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

We have a report in SSRS that has drop down list parameters that are fed by a shared datasource and query.

If I use ReportViewer to view the report these work as expected.

However, I'm also using the SSRS web service to pull out the parameters and the available values. In this instance when drop downs are moved from a manually entered list to a query the available values list is empty.

I'm assuming the problem is because the web services simply gropes the RDL file and does not execute the queries attached to the parameters.

My question is, is there any way to have it do this or to get the available values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading MSDN it seems the answer is to call GetReportParameters() and set ForRendering to true:

> If ForRendering has a value of false, the parameter meta data returned represents the parameter data that is currently associated with the specified report. If any parameters values are based on a query and you are interested in returning the query-based parameters valid values list, you need to set ForRendering to true, In addition, for query based parameters, you need to ensure that you have passed in all of the credential information required to return the query parameters.